# Sorting dates with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date

How can I get a date from an array if I don't have all the parts of the date.

I have a dictionary with different dates and try to get all dates from it with the month of June.

```
let dict = ["15-06-2019" : "red",
            "19-10-2019" : "green", 
            "05-08-2018" : "yellow", 
            "20-06-2019" : "orange"]
```

Comment: What is it: array or dictionary? What are you going to accomplish: *sort* or *filter*?

Comment: It is an dictionary and I want to filter it

Comment: You have strings, not dates. The first step of sorting the dates would be to parse the strings into `Date` objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter`

```
let dict = ["15-06-2019" : "red", "19-10-2019" : "green", "05-08-2018" : "yellow", "20-06-2019" : "ornge"]
let filtered = dict.filter { $0.key.range(of: "-06-") != nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here, but based on the structure of the dictionary I'm presuming the dates work day-month-year. If that's the case and you're trying to just get the dates in June the code below should work.

```
let dict = ["15-06-2019" : "red", "19-10-2019" : "green", "05-08-2018" : "yellow", "20-06-2019" : "ornge"]

var juneDates = [String]()
for (keys, values) in dict{

    let dates = keys.components(separatedBy: "-")

    if dates[1] == "06"{
        juneDates.append(keys)
        print(juneDates)
    }
}
```